Compact subspace of $l_1$

Given a fixed $a \in l_1$ (space of sequences with sum absolute value less than infinity over reals).  Is there a general way to
determine if $F :=\{x\in l_1 :|x_i|≤a_i $ for all $i≥1 \}$ is compact ?

The cases individually where $a_i$ has 1) finitely many non-zero terms and 2) infinitely many non-zero terms should be solvable by just defining a sequence in $F$ that sets a single component $x_i = a_i$ (i.e. it is not compact if a has infinitely many non-zero terms).

This post might be helpful

The space of sequences with "sum [of the absolute values] less than infinity" is usually called l1, not l2.

@SassatelliGiulio edited, thanks.

Even better, call it $l_1$, not l1.

Do you really want $F$ to be a subset of $l_2$? Should't it be again $l_1$? And $l_1$ is the space of sequences with sum of absolute values less than infinity. So better write $\lvert x_i \rvert \le \lvert a_i \rvert$.

The set $F$ is compact iff the sequence a has finitely many non-zero terms.
To see this, first suppose that $a$ has finitely many non-zero terms. Then $F$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is the number of non-zero terms of a. Since closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact, it follows that $F$ is compact.
Now suppose that $a$ has infinitely many non-zero terms. We will show that $F$ is not compact by constructing a sequence in $F$ that has no convergent subsequence. Let $x_n$ be the sequence defined by
$x_n(i) = \begin{cases} a_i & \text{if } i \leq n, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$
It is easy to see that $x_n \in F$ for all $n$. However, the sequence $x_n$ has no convergent subsequence, because the $l_1$ norm of $x_n$ is equal to the sum of the absolute values of the first $n$ terms of a, which is infinite.
It is well-known fact that $F$ is homeomorphic to closed ball of euclidean spaces of such dimension. The proof of this fact is like under.

Let $n$ be the number of non-zero terms of $a$. We can define a homeomorphism $h$ between $F$ and the closed ball $B$ in $\mathbf R^n$ with radius $||a||_1$ (the $l_1$ norm of $a$) centered at the origin.
$h: F \to B$; $h(x) = (x_1, ..., x_n)$, $h^{-1}: B \to F$.  $h^{-1}(y) = (y_1, ..., y_n, 0, 0, ...)$.
$h$ is continuous because the $l_1$ norm is continuous. $h^{-1}$ is also continuous because the $l_1$ norm is continuous. Therefore, $h$ is a homeomorphism.


'the sum of the absolute values of the first $n$ terms of $a$, which is infinite' No the assumption is the opposite: $a\in \ell_1$. In fact $F$ is always compact (and actually already $a\in\ell_2$ suffices)
